# Uninstall umake on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: uninstall, ubuntu-make

On Ubuntu 16.04, I have `umake` installed at `/usr/bin/umake`. When I run `umake --version` it reports

```
18.05
```

I just used `snap install ubuntu-make --classic` to install the latest version, and this is installed at `/snap/bin/ubuntu-make.umake`. When I run `ubuntu-make.umake --version` it reports

```
20.04+snap678
```

I had expected the newer version to overwrite the original and to create an alias for itself at `/usr/bin/umake`, but now I have two copies of `umake` in two different places. I have tried `sudo apt remove umake`, but this does nothing useful:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package umake
```

Sanity check: Does it make sense to remove the older version and to create a symbolic link for the newer version at `usr/bin/umake`? If so, how do I uninstall version 18.05?

Comment: The package name must be `ubuntu-make`. Try `sudo apt remove ubuntu-make`.

Comment: That works! Thank you. If you would like to make your comment into an answer, I will be able to mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`umake` is actually short for `ubuntu-make`. To remove that run

```
sudo apt remove ubuntu-make
```

For more, see [ubuntu-make - Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make).